# Getting "Error: no such option: --extra" for cci task run dx_push --extra -f

Tags: cumulusci

I am trying to push the force-app directory metadata into a scratch org,I am getting below error when I run `cci task run dx_push --extra -f`

```
ci task run dx_push --extra -f  
Error: no such option: --extra 
Run this command for more information about debugging errors: cci error --help
```

Basically I am trying to force (overwrite) to push the source to a scratch org.

As per the [documentation](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html#dx-push) ,We can pass the extra arguments

**

```
dx_push
Description: Uses sfdx to push the force-app directory metadata into a scratch org
Class: cumulusci.tasks.sfdx.SFDXOrgTask
Command Syntax
$ cci task run dx_push
Options
--command COMMAND
Required
The full command to run with the sfdx cli.
Default: force:source:push
--extra EXTRA
Optional
Append additional options to the command
```

**

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this and found it worked fine with CumulusCI 3.60.0 (the latest version). Please make sure you're up to date.

Here's the log:

```
sea-dreamin main $ cci task run dx_push --extra -f --org dev
[06/10/22 21:18:49] Creating scratch org with command: sfdx force:org:create  -f orgs/dev.json -w 120 -n --durationdays 7 -a None__dev adminEmail=david@ktema.org         
[06/10/22 21:19:26] Successfully created scratch org: 00D17000000hQbtEAE, username: test-hdyltibmxdcx@example.com                                                         
                    Generating scratch org user password with command: sfdx force:user:password:generate -u test-hdyltibmxdcx@example.com                                 
[06/10/22 21:19:28] Getting org info from Salesforce CLI for test-hdyltibmxdcx@example.com                                                                                
[06/10/22 21:19:30] Org info updated, writing to keychain                                                                                                                 
                    Beginning task: SFDXOrgTask                                                                                                                           
                    As user: test-hdyltibmxdcx@example.com                                                                                                                
                    In org: 00D17000000hQbt                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                          
                    Running command: sfdx force:source:push -f -u test-hdyltibmxdcx@example.com
```

I tested with and without quotes around the `-f` argument and both translated into the correct SFDX command (shown on the last line above).

Comment: Thanks David, This worked after upgrading CumulusCI to 3.60.0